# has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b5596468 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask, memory-leaks

I got leak error when I trying to start new activity from the a current activity, and I think that the current activity is closed correctly before starting the new one, so can you help to specify where is the wrong in my code?

```
package com.example.mediastore;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.mediastore.JSONParser;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter.LengthFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    Button login;
    EditText inputusername;
    EditText inputpassword;
    private static String url_users = "http://10.0.2.2/mediastore/android/usersLogin.php";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    boolean startActivity;

    @Override
    public void finish()
    {
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
        {
             pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        inputusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        inputpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);



        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               if(v == login) {
                    login.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button2));
               }
               String u = inputusername.getText().toString();
               String p = inputpassword.getText().toString();

                if(u.equals("")||p.equals(""))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill these two fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else{
                    new userLogin().execute();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class userLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging user..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String username = inputusername.getText().toString();
            String password = inputpassword.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_users,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat for response
            Log.d("Login Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    startActivity = true;

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done

            pDialog.dismiss();

            if(startActivity){  
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

This is the log cat:

```
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629): Activity com.example.mediastore.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b5596468 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mediastore.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b5596468 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at com.example.mediastore.LoginActivity$userLogin.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:93)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at com.example.mediastore.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:75)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-04 10:50:27.129: E/WindowManager(1629):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the new errors:

```
10-04 14:02:14.414: E/JSON Parser(1909): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-04 14:02:14.434: W/dalvikvm(1909): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4d01908)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at com.example.mediastore.LoginActivity$userLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:123)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at com.example.mediastore.LoginActivity$userLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-04 14:02:14.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     ... 4 more
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909): Activity com.example.mediastore.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b55038e8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mediastore.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b55038e8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at com.example.mediastore.LoginActivity$userLogin$1.run(LoginActivity.java:99)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-04 14:02:19.734: E/WindowManager(1909):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try putting finish() only after startActivity(i); in your onPostExecute method.

I have experienced that calling finish also deletes global declared variables and many other things happen in the background.

Edit 1.

Also remove super.onPreExecute(); and put this code in onPreExecute:

```
    Handler h= new Handler();
    h.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging user..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
      }
    });
```

There might be a error or two in spelling, so dont copy/paste, rather type it in Eclipse your self.

Comment: Try commenting the whole code in your onPreExecute method, so that it does nothing(including super.onPreExecute, remove that its completely unnecessary) ...its should run ok? If it runs ok, then you should use a Handler to post your Dialog.

Comment: I got new errors in addition to the same error.
edited the question.

Comment: Check out the first line in error: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-04 14:02:14.434: W/dalvikvm(1909): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4d01908)

Comment: You get error while parsing JSON, check out what you are parsing and how....the app crashes there and the following error occur as a consequence of that i presume...

Comment: @JanBo, for me it's work with super() in pre/post execute normally.